# An abelian variety not isogenous to a Jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

In the [L-functions and Modular Forms Database](http://www.lmfdb.org/Variety/Abelian/Fq/2/5/af_q) is an isogeny class of an abelian variety of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb F_5$. They claim that it is principally polarizable but not the Jacobian of a curve over $\mathbb F_5$.

The two ways they suggest this is usually checked is:

1. Show that a point count of the associated virtual curve of the abelian variety is negative.
2. Show that there is an extension $\mathbb F_{p^d}\subset \mathbb F_{p^n}$ such that the curve has fewer points over the bigger field than over the smaller field.

Neither of these hold for the example linked above. I also checked that the Weil bound for a genus $2$ curve over $\mathbb F_{p^d}$ holds for the first few virtual point counts.

1. How are they concluding that this isogeny class doesn't contain a Jacobian?
2. More generally, what other techniques are there that help us rule out a principally polarized abelian variety being isogenous to a Jacobian?

Comment: In principle, at least, one can enumerate all curves of a given genus over $\mathbb{F}_5$, and compute their Frobenius polynomials. If none of them match the given curve, then you're done.

Comment: PS: sorry, I meant "if none of them match the given abelian variety", of course.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Hi David. Thank you. Your method works but I was hoping it would be some invariant of the AV that would be less brute force, something in the vein of a virtual point count.

Comment: I agree, I'd also be happy to see a more conceptual approach.

Comment: So this ended up being a paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02067 :)